# Modify arrow function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, arrow-functions

I am new to .js and want to change this arrow function to normal function, for personal interest

```
module.exports.endpoint = fn =>
(req, res) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res))
        .catch((err) => {
            this.jsonOutHandler(err, null, res);
        });
};
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: add `function` in front, surround the parameter(s) in brackets (here it's just `fn` ), remove the `=>`, add `{ }` around the body and a `return`.

Comment: `= function(fn) { return function(req, res) {` etc

Comment: module.exports.endpoint = function (fn) {
 return function fun(req, res)  {
   return Promise.resolve(fn(req, res))
        .catch(function (err)  {
            return this.jsonOutHandler(err, null, res);
        });
}};

Comment: @MFuatNUROĞLU doesn't return anything.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, I've fixed it